# Using php to get data from database but it only return one result

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to get data form database.
It should return three results but it only return one of the results.

How can I fix the problem?

Here is my code:

```
$statement3 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM client_ble_gateway WHERE username = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement3, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement3);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement3);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement3, $ble_id, $client_id, $alias, $serial_number, $share_data, $latitude, $longitude,$username);


while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement3)){

    $res["ble_id"]=$ble_id;
    $res["alias"]=$alias;
    $res["serial_number"]=$serial_number;
}

$res=array($ble_id, $alias, $serial_number);
echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use multidimensional array to get all data

```
$result = array();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement3)){

    $res["ble_id"]=$ble_id;
    $res["alias"]=$alias;
    $res["serial_number"]=$serial_number;
    $result[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```